# How can I use one partial view to display similar data for two different viewmodels?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to render a partial view as follows:

```
The viewModel for book.cshtml looks like:
public class EditViewModel
{
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
}
In the book.cshtml file:
@{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/_Tracking.cshtml", Model.Book); }
```

and

```
The viewModel for magazine.cshtml looks like:
public class EditViewModel
{
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public Magazine Magazine { get; set; }
}
In the magazine.cshtml file:
@{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/_Tracking.cshtml", Model.Magazine); }
```

Both the Book and Magazine classes derive from a base class:

```
 public class PubBase 
   {
        public string PubDate { get; set; }
   }
```

In the partial view I would like to show:

```
@model ????
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PubDate)
```

I have tried a few different things like casting the Model.Book and Model.Magazine to a a view model that has PubDate but that gives me errors. Is there a way I can implement this. I saw some recent posts about this but I don't think it applies to my situation. I hope I can get some suggestions.

Thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PubBase as model for the view

```
@model PubBase
```